# three.js MeshPhongMaterial and emissiveMap

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a example of how to use the emissiveMap in MeshPhongMaterial or MeshLambert? I did try everything to achieve it but nothing works and in the documentation http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial
you can read something about this parameter. I did try to set the emissive Color also but the complete mesh gets brighter and not the parts that i declared in the emissiveMap. The emissiveMap was complete black with only parts white where it should have "glow".

I want to achieve a spaceship that has glowing windows like here 
https://sketchfab.com/models/028ba99d11a641f4a285d53401eefd8a

Comment: Can you show a simple live example to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and your continuous support in three.js. It works in my live example. Here is the link to it http://never-mage.de/modelviewer/emissive.html